# Kerfuffle rules?

Tags: untagged

I recently bought Kerfuffle from a thrift store with no rules. I have managed to piece together most of them from online videos but could someone point me to a pdf. It does not seem to be on bgg

Comment: Maybe you can contact the manufacturer so they can provide you with a set of rules.

Comment: Rules PDF are linked from the manufacturer's page: https://www.universitygames.com/kerfuffle

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson Want to turn that into an answer?

Comment: I tend to get marked off for link-only answers. Anyway, I've submitted the link to Boardgamegeek as well, so I doubt if this question will garner future hits.

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I was looking for. I agree that I expect this will get very few hits now that BGG will show the link.